# I need to show notice on wordpress Dashboard only

Tags: wordpress, notice

I am trying to make a notice on wordpress dashboard only. but when i paste this code in function.php notice show on all the pages like, Post , Authors , Pages everywhere. I just want only show on main dashboard Page.

```
function sample_admin_notice__success() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the current screen

```php
function sample_admin_notice__success() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

if (is_admin()) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    
    if ($screen -> id == "dashboard") {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
    }
}
```

Comment: i paste the above code in function.php then i system showing error please check the attaches SCREENSHOT Link:

https://prnt.sc/1w0d4df